# Click on every instance of a certain word in a page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Im trying to program something using JQuery that will search a webpage for every instance of a certain word and then click on it. How would I do this?

I currently have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function follow(texttofind, texttoexclude, setinterval){
        var buttons = $( "*:contains('"+texttofind+"'):not(:contains('"+texttoexclude+"'))" );
        var i = 0;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            while(i <= buttons.length) {
                i++
                buttons[i].scrollIntoView();
                buttons[i].click();
            }
        }, setinterval);
    }
    follow("text", "200");
});
```

Comment: You declare `follow`, but never call it. Also your `for` has a syntax problem.

Comment: The follow is called at a different part. What is the syntax problem with the for?

Comment: Please check your browser console for errors. You have an obvious string concatenation problem also

Answer (score 0):

The value of `i` is changing every time the `while` loops.

You can simplify it all by using `$.each()` instead of `while`/`[i]`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function follow(texttofind, texttoexclude, setinterval) {
    var buttons = $("*:contains('" + texttofind + "'):not(:contains('" + texttoexclude + "'))");

    interval = setInterval(function() {
      buttons.each(function(i, button) {
        button.scrollIntoView();
        button.click();
      });
    }, setinterval);
  }

  follow("text", "stop", "2000");
});
```

See [**demo here**](http://jsbin.com/horihetaho/edit?html,js,output).